# MS SQL Server limitation during edmx schema update

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

during updating model from (big) database in EF 6 I encountered problem with SQL server limitation:

An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.

I can see in profiler that during updating model, EF is trying to run sp_executesql procedure with 2XXX parameters. Is there any solution/workaround for this problem (and I don't mean splitting edmx schema)?

Table valued parameter will not help me there because I am not talking about querying to business entities but updating model by EF which I do not know how much I can control.

Comment: Move to the EF Reverse POCO template?

Comment: Sounds like kind a hack to me because I already got a db ready :)

Comment: OK, after some research it looks like that its realy needed to go for  EF Reverse POCO template.